# Breadth First Search Block Puzzle

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, breadth-first-search

I am creating a program that will be given a text file as output with the board's dimension and the piece id along with the piece width and length. The goal is to arrange all blocks in the board correctly. Currently, my program takes forever to come up with a solution. I need help optimizing or figuring out what I need to fix. I am trying to implement Breadth First Search to do this correctly.
I will attach the text file and source file.
I added pictures at the bottom to show the input and what the output should be.
TEXT FILE - first line is the board dimensions and the rest are piece ID, piece width, piece length.

```
10,10
1,10,1
2,1,10
3,1,5
4,3,5
5,20,2
6,1,5
7,1,5
8,2,5
```

SOURCE FILE The Solve method does all of the heavy work and implements BFS

```
import argparse, copy
import queue
import copy
import numpy as np

class PuzzleBoard():

    def __init__(self, board_length, board_width ):
        self.l = board_length
        self.w = board_width
        self.state = [[0 for _ in range(board_width)] for _ in range(board_length)]
        self.used_piece = []

    # Input: point - tuple cotaining (row_index, col_index) of point in self.state
    # Returns true if point is out of bounds; otherwise, returns false
    def __out_of_bounds(self, point):
        if(point < 0 or point > (len(self.state)) or (point > (self.state[0]))):
            return True
        return False

    # Finds the next available open space in the PuzzleBoard (looking from the top-left in row-major order)
    def __next(self):
        for i in range(len(self.state)) :
            for j in range(len(self.state[0])):
                if (self.state[i][j] == 0):
                    return (i, j)
        return False

    # Input: piece - PuzzlePiece object
    # Check if piece fits in the next available space (determined by __next method above)

    def fits(self, piece):

        position = self.__next()
        if not position:
            return False

        #if piece will be out bounds when place rotate to see if that helps
        if((( piece.w + position[0] ) > len( self.state )) or (( piece.l + position[1] )> len( self.state[0] ))):
            piece.rotate()
            
        if((( piece.w + position[0] ) > len( self.state )) or (( piece.l + position[1] )> len( self.state[0] ))):
            return False
        

        return True

    # Input: piece - PuzzlePiece object
    # Insert piece into the next available position on the board and update state
    def place(self, piece):
        position = self.__next()
        if self.fits(piece):
            for i in range(position[0], position[0] + piece.w ):
                for j in range(position[1], position[1] + piece.l):
                    if((( piece.w + position[0] ) > len( self.state )) or (( piece.l + position[1] )> len( self.state[0] ))):
                        return
                    if(self.state[i][j]== 0):
                        #self.used_piece.append(piece)
                        self.state[i][j] = piece.id
                    else:
                        continue
            return position

    def check(self, piece):
        position = self.__next()
        if(position[0] + piece.w > self.w or position[1] + piece.l > self.l):
            return False
        return True

    # Returns whether the board has been filledwith pieces
    def completed(self):
        return True if not self.__next() else False

    def copy(self):
        copied = PuzzleBoard(self.l, self.w)
        copied.state = copy.deepcopy(self.state)
        return copied

class PuzzlePiece():

    def __init__(self, pid, length, width):
        self.id = pid
        self.l = length
        self.w = width
        itfits = False

    def rotate(self):
        temp = self.l
        self.l = self.w
        self.w = temp

    def orientation(self):
        return "H" if self.w >= self.l else "V"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID: {self.id}, LENGTH: {self.l}, WIDTH: {self.w}, ROTATED: {self.rotated}"

def parse_input(filepath) :

    parsed = {'board' : {}, 'pieces' : {}}
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        file_contents = f.read().strip().split("\n")
        board_length, board_width = file_contents[0].strip().split(",")
        parsed['board']['length'] = int(board_length)
        parsed['board']['width'] = int(board_width)
        for i in range(1, len(file_contents)):
            #FIX: the issue was fix
            pid, l, w = file_contents[i].strip().split(",")
            pid, l, w = int(pid), int(l), int(w)
            parsed['pieces'][pid] = {}
            parsed['pieces'][pid]['length'] = l
            parsed['pieces'][pid]['width'] = w
    return parsed

def helper(board, piece):
    unused = []
    #for piece in pieces:
    if board.fits(piece):
        position = board.place(piece)
        board.used_piece.append((piece, position))

    return board





def solve(board, remaining, used_pieces=[]):
    # HINT: Recursion might help.7
    poss = queue.Queue()
    poss.put(board)

    currboard = PuzzleBoard(len(board.state), len(board.state[0]))
    while not currboard.completed():
        currboard = poss.get()
        #print(currboard.state)
        for piece in remaining:
            fakeboard = copy.deepcopy(currboard)
            if(not (piece.id in np.array(fakeboard.state))):
                #if( fakeboard.check(piece)):
                poss.put(helper(fakeboard, piece))

    print("Suff done")
    return currboard

        
    


    '''if(len(remaining) != 0):
        board, used_pieces, unused_pieces = helper(board, remaining, used_pieces)
        if board.completed():
            return board, used_pieces
        for i in board.state:
            print(i)
        print("\n \n")
        return solve(board, unused_pieces, used_pieces)
    return board'''

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    parsed = parse_input(args.input)
    board = PuzzleBoard(parsed['board']['length'], parsed['board']['width'])
    pieces = []
    for k, v in parsed['pieces'].items():
        pieces.append(PuzzlePiece(k, v['length'], v['width']))
    solved = solve(board, pieces)
    if not solved:
        print("No solution found for given input.")
    else:
        print("Solution found.")
        board = solved
        for u, position in solved.used_piece:
            print(f"Piece ID: {u.id}, Position:{position}, Orientation: {u.orientation()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to CR! I note the comment in your code `#TODO: Bug in this function. Positions are not correct after solution is found.`. Does your code actually work? This site is for working code to the best of your knowledge.

Comment: Yes, it does. I'm sorry I forgot to remove the TODO comments. But the program works as it should. It just takes forever to come up with a solution. I tried to implement Breadth First Search but ended up using Brute Force. I am just curious on how I could make it better.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I recommend [editing the post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/259432/edit) to remove that comment.

Comment: The post is edited and Its all set.

Comment: I believe this is a variant of pentomino tiling, which can be framed as an exact cover problem and solved with Knuth's Algorithm X. Unfortunately, that algorithm is still a brute force search. The algorithm doesn't eliminate the need for brute force; rather, it just provides a smart way to make backtracking very efficient. Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) for more details. You can almost certainly speed up your code; but the problem itself is NP-complete and will not scale to large puzzle sizes. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: Also, and this is just a pedantic detail: BFS is a brute force search -- just a certain flavor of brute-force. DFS is too. In order to be non-brute-force, an algorithm needs to leverage some aspect of the problem to make the search more intelligent than merely walking the full graph until a solution is found.